# wordpress gutenberg editor and custom block attributes

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I am coding a custom block type. Its displaying in the editor and I can select one.
I wanted to add attributes to the block, so I added them as follows in register_block_type:

```
register_block_type(
            'ed/eventlist',
            array(
                'editor_script' => 'edeventblocks',
                'render_callback' => array(self::class,'display_eventlist'),
                'attributes' => array('when' => array('type' => 'string','enum' => array('past','future'))),
```

I assumed that by adding the 'attributes', when I added the block to a page, there would be block attributes in the editor side-panel that I could set - but no attributes appear - any help appreciated.

I expected that when I had added attributes, they would automatically be editable in the gutenberg editor block attributes panel

Answer (score 0):

Gutenberg does not include the side bar editor just by adding the `attributes` property to your block.

You need to include the `<InspectorControls />` block from the `@wordpress/block-editor` package.
**Example:**

#### Block Registration

Register your block using the `block.json` file.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
  "apiVersion": 3,
  "name": "block-name/block",
  "title": "Block Name",
  "category": "layout",
  "icon": "superhero",
  "description": "This is a test block for the FSE Ultimate Blocks plugin.",
  "keywords": [ "fse", "block" ],
  "version": "1.0",
  "textdomain": "your-text-domain",
  "editorScript": "file:index.js",
  "editorStyle": "file:index.css",
  "style": "file:style-index.css"
}
```

#### Editor Script

```
import { useBlockProps, InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor'
import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components'

const Edit = ({ attributes, setAttributes }) => {
   const { message } = attributes
   return (
     <div {...useBlockProps()}>
       <InspectorControls>
       {/* MANIPULATE ATTRIBUTES HERE */}
        <TextControl 
          value={ message }
          onChange={ ( val ) => setAttributes( { message: val } )} 
        />
       </InspectorControls>
     </div>
   )
}
```

*Further reading:*

**Sidebar**
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbar-and-sidebar/

**Components for manipulating attributes**
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/